# Populate HTML textboxes from external PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, html

I need to read values from my PHP files SQL query and populate textboxes on my HTML page. Can someone help me with how I can retrieve this information. A sample is below, which I also use for my jQuery autocomplete textbox located on the html page which works fine.

default.html

```
<input type="text" class="queryString" id="first">
```

result.php

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

$queryString = $_GET['term'];

$tsql = "SELECT [FirstName] FROM [Staff] WHERE [FirstName] = '$queryString%'";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql); 
$data = array();
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC))     
{   
$data = array_merge( $data, array_values($row) );
sort($data, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
}
echo json_encode($data);

$first = row[FirstName];
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(function () {
    $("#queryString").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
            url: "result.php",
            data: { term: $("#queryString").val(), searchby: $("#ddlSearch").val()},
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
                success: function(data){
                response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        multiple: true, 
        multipleSeparator: " "
    });
});
```

Comment: You could call the external PHP file via ajax and retrieve the information (e.g. json encoded). Watch out for SQL injections!

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, could you give me and example? I'll past my current function above for you. Thanks

Comment: @user2168287 do you mean an autocomplete

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is on the HTML page there is an autocomplete textbox (working) that retrieves a list of users from a database. Once the user has been select and hits the 'GO' button I need it to then populate all the other textboxes on the HTML page with the required information from the database for the user that was selected. Hope that explains it a little more. Are the suggestions on this page likely to work or should I be looking at some other way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST', 
    url: 'result.php', 
    data: {
      'trim':$('#first').val()
        },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) { 
  $.each(result, function(index, el) {

       alert(el); // will alert each value
      });
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, looks similar to the code addition I just added above. what does the 'alert(data[0]);' do? How do I then apply it to the required textbox

Comment: SarathSprakash, I'm still confused by how this would work can you help me out. I have a HTML page with multiple textboxes one of which uses the jquery autocomplete to get a list users based on a remote PHP SQL query. Once the autocomplete textbox is populated with the required user I want to click a GO button and once again remotely get all required details for that user from a PHP SQL query and populate the other textboxes with information such as address, country etc. Hope that helps

Comment: @user2168287 now I understood your need, I will have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Try it like,

```
$('#first').on('keyup',function(){ 
    $.ajax({
        url:'result.php',
        data:{term:$(this).val()},
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(json){
            console.log(json);
        }
    });
});
```

Read [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this and see if I can get it working